# Proof plan for P ≠ NP

Tags: complexity-theory, p-vs-np

Let $M$ be a Turing Machine for SAT. We want to encode certain paths of $M$ in a very short way in order to diagonalize against the paths.

For each natural number $k$, we will have a formula $\phi$ of length $n$ that does the following: $\phi$ is satisfiable iff the assignment encodes a run of $M$ on $\phi$ of length $n^k$ that ends in the reject state.

Suppose SAT can be computed in time $n^k$, and let $\phi$ be the formula associated with $k$. If $\phi$ is satisfiable, then the satisfying assignment encodes a run of $M$ on $\phi$ ending in the reject state. If $\phi$ is not satisfiable, then by our assumption there is a run of $M$ on $\phi$ of length $n^k$ ending in the reject state. An encoding of this path satisfies $\phi$. Contradiction. Therefore, SAT cannot be computed in time $n^k$.

Any opinions?  I'm curious if anyone has an immediate reason why this wouldn't work.  (I'm quite aware that it would be difficult.)

Comment: Please use MathJax to improve the formatting of your post.

Comment: How do you encode $\phi$ in length $n$?

Comment: Does your argument refute the time hierarchy theorem, by any chance?

Comment: You are claiming to have a solution for a well-known, difficult open problem. This is [an extraordinary claim requiring extraordinary evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcello_Truzzi#.22Extraordinary_claims.22). You have not provided such so there is not much to talk about. Even if you had, this would not be a good post for SE; it is not our goal here to make broad advances to science in a single post. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/109/) for a related discussion.

Comment: What's more, proof-checking questions are also not well-suited for this platform. What's a _specific_ question you have about your proof outline?

Comment: Good grief, I'm not claiming I found a solution!  It's just an idea. You know, people have ideas and they bounce them around sometimes.  Obviously I'm in the wrong place.

Comment: Question available for bounty in 2 days???  I'm not interested in any of this, what's the world coming to?

Answer (score 2):

Before I explain what went wrong, notice the following red flag:

Let $T(n)$ be some arbitrary function representing some run-time. What would not work from this "proof" if we replace $n^k$ by $T(n)$? From what I see, pretty much nothing. Does that mean that $SAT$ is not solveable in any run-time? of course not!

---

Now to the actual problem: Each $\Phi_k$ depends on $n$, so let us call it instead $\Phi_k^n$. Notice, that the size of $\Phi_k^n$ would **not** be $n$, since it takes a lot of "space" to represent this formula. In fact, its size woul most likely be way bigger than $n^k$. When you run $M$ on $\Phi_k^n$, the runtime would take $O(|\Phi_k^n|^k)\approx O((n^k)^k)$ and not $O(n^k)$, since the runtime depends on the size of the input $\Phi_k^n$. This completely nullifies your argument that this is a contradiction.

---

As a side note, if you do actually manage to encode $\Phi_k^n$ in some magical way with size $O(n)$, then congratulations! Your argument holds and $P\neq NP$. But clearly its not easy to encode it like that... good luck :)

Comment: I haven't figured out how to properly format my responses yet, my apologies.  First of all, this is not a proof, it's not remotely close to being a proof, it's just an idea.  When I say that the length of phi_k is n, I mean that the length of the representation of phi_k is n.

Comment: Yes, the problem is that you cant have the length of the representation of $\Phi_k^n$ to be $n$, but also to contain the expression of $M(\phi)=false$ for $\phi$ of length $n$, since that expression is most likely to take up at least $n^k$.

Comment: The length of phi_k by definition is n.  I'm using n to represent the length of the input.  The variable n doesn't represent anything else.  The idea is to represent this particular path of M in a short way.  It would have to be something new.  I don't know how to do it, I'm just tossing around the idea.

Comment: if $\Phi_k^n$ is of length $n$ then it represents a computation of $M$ on some extremely short input, something that is way smaller than $n$.

Comment: We would need a new way to represent computations of M (not all computations, just some special ones).  If the formula is of length n and M is bounded by n^k, then the length of the computation would be n^k in the worst case.  I agree, a formula of length n can't handle something of size n^k.  We couldn't just list the transitions or have a computation tableau.  We would need an entirely new method.  The number 2^10^10^80 has more digits than there are particles in the universe, but we can represent it in a concise way.  We would have to do something similar for M.

Comment: Then you need to properly define them before you start using them. Its not obvious why such formula exist, and even less obvious (if it is even possible) to write them in some short formula

Comment: Will you people *puh-leeeze* get it through your heads that it's just an idea.  It's completely unobvious that such a formula would exist, I agree.  I'm just brainstorming.  I don't need someone to tell me what I have to think about first and what I have to think about second.  Obviously I've come to the wrong place.  This was a mistake, I apologize.

Comment: No need to apologize, its good to brainstorm (even ideas you know you wont be able to solve!), and its even better to discuss your ideas with other people :) I simply tried to provide the explanation of where such an argument falls. Now its your job to figure out if you can solve this problem and how (or just ponder on why it is so difficult)